# Wow & Battle.net accounts

Tags: world-of-warcraft, battle.net

I've bought the standard MoP version that's tied(?) to US. So is it possible for me to play on the EU realms too ?

Do you need separate battle.net accounts/game-subscriptions/clients to play on the US and EU realms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,
You need different account to play on EU if you only have a US account.
You don't need different game clients as you can change in the files to go from US to EU.
If you want to make a EU battle net account you can go to http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/.

**To change from US to EU**

1. Go into your "World of Warcraft" folder
2. Go into the "WTF" folder
3. Open the "Config" file with "Notepad"
4. Make your top 2 lines look like this. (Copy and paste it if you like)

   ```
   SET locale "enGB"
   SET installLocale "enUS"
   ```

Comment: Is there any way of transferring a US account to EU ?

Comment: I believe there is, but I think you have to contact blizzard support for that.

Answer (score -2):

You need to buy an EU account even though you have a US account. If you already have an EU account, you can change the client locale from US to EU by changing a couple things in your `Config.wtf` file in the WTF folder:

`SET locale "enGB"`
`SET installLocale "enGB"`